# Install python-pip on Ubuntu 14.04.2 Issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

Attempting to install python-pip on a *fresh* Ubuntu 14.04.2 VM.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

The error I get indicates some basic `libc` package can't be found:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-52.86
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Fetched 26.1 MB in 4s (5918 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-52.86_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

And indeed, hitting the URL listed from a browser throws a 404.

Same issue happens when trying to install `python-dev` and `python3-pip`.

What's the workaround?

---

**EDIT - Solved**

The problem was actually that I was building the VM using vagrant and docker.

The `RUN sudo apt-get update` step in my Dockerfile was cached for some reason, meaning it was being skipped. Consequently, `python-pip` was probably looking for an outdated dependency.

Comment: So how did you solve this?

Comment: yeah, i believe it's a bit unclear above. i solved it by running `sudo apt-get update` and ensuring it ran before attempting to install `python-pip`. the error was specific to the fact that i was building a docker image and the apt-get update step hadn't ran.

Comment: Yes, i got round it by just adding a comment to the apt-get update command : `apt-get update #redo` .. this forced docker to not use the cache

Comment: yep, it's a bit janky but it works! not sure if docker has a better way of specifying to not use a cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a virtualenv, where all I had to do was this:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Now that virtualenv is up to date - but I didn't have to mess with the rest of Ubuntu's pip on this system. Probably the best way to go, given how old Ubuntu's is and not wanting to mess with their packaging system.

Answer (score -1):

Your are trying to access the package from source but not responding:

Here are some steps to resolve this issue:

1. Check Ubuntu Version: First, ensure you are using a supported version of Ubuntu. You can check your Ubuntu version by running lsb_release -a in your terminal.
2. Update Repository Sources: If you're on a supported version, try changing your repository sources.

3.Upgrade Your System: If you haven't upgraded your system in a while, run the following commands and make sure all the packages are up to date.

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade